# Error 403 when trying to read emails using EWS

Tags: c#, oauth, exchangewebservices

I'm receiving error 403 when trying to read e-mails using code below

```
 IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithTenantId(tenant)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, instance, tenant)))
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .Build();

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            if (result != null)
            {
                string token = result.AccessToken;

                service = new ExchangeService
                {
                    Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
                    Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(token),
                    ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, email)
                };

                service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", email);
            }
            var emails = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(10));
```

On Azure portal I did:

- Register new application and copied tenant id, client id, client secret
- Added EWS.AccessAsUser.All in API auth.

But still receiving 403 - Forbidden when trying to get email from inbox

What am I missing?

Comment: `EWS.AccessAsUser.All` is for delegated auth. you need to add `EWS.full_access_as_app` because you use app only auth

Answer (score 0):

Select API permissions under Manage. Confirm that the EWS.AccessAsUser.All permission is listed.

follow the manual below https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth